# After starting process closing web browser and seeing updated values on next time visiting page

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, background-process, exchangewebservices

I have implemented email migration from one exchange server to another, using ajax call to c# action, in my web page.

I have implemented a button to dynamically add more input values for more than one migration at the same time, but now I want to close the web browser and keep the multiple migrations running in the background, and when a user visits the same page again, they should be able to see the updated progress values, like 25% migrated or complete etc.

Ajax to call action:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/Exchange',
    data: JSON.stringify({ url: surl, password: pass, username: uname }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        // returned values
    }
});
```

Action in Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Exchange(string username, string password, string url)
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.Url = new Uri(url);
        ExportMIMEEmail(service, count); //call to export mails;

        return Json(true);
    }
```

I want to be able to check the progress of the email migration after re-visiting the web page. How can this be achieved? Please answer with example code if possible.

Comment: You can't do that. IIS is known to kill processes that aren't associated to a request.

Comment: But migration is running in the background even after closing web browser, migration completes, i have checked destination account, all source emails are migrated.
Please, tell me if there is some other way to achieve all this, want to complete this task as soon as possible

Comment: I mean it CAN work. But you can't rely on it working. Better to run it as a console app, and out put to the console the status.

Comment: ok, how would i achieve multiple migration at same time in console/window application , can you help me in that because i don't have good knowledge of window app.